# STL container library - Is it legal to call allocate/deallocate on different instances of the allocator class?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, allocator

First of all, I don't think it is. But, I've observed such a behavior with MSVC 10.0 in Debug mode. I'm using a custom `allocator` class which relies on the user to pass only pointers allocated on the same instance to `deallocate`. However, in Release mode, my code is working.

Is this a bug or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard requires that any allocator be able to deallocate memory produced by any other allocator of the same type, even if it's a totally different instance.  This is required to get `list::splice` working correctly.  It's largely considered a design flaw in the C++ spec, and in C++0x they're introducing a set of fixups to allocators to rememdy this.  In the meantime, any allocator you use in the STL containers must not have its own local state.

**EDIT**: For those of you who want the original language on this, here's §20.1.5/4 of the C++ ISO spec:

> Implementations of containers described in this International Standard are permitted to assume that their
>   Allocator template parameter meets the following two additional requirements beyond those in Table 32.
>
> — All instances of a given allocator type are **required to be interchangeable** and always compare equal to
>   each other.

In the latest ISO draft of the C++0x standard, this requirement is no longer present.  The default `std::allocator` will still maintain this invariant as required, but it doesn't look like you'll have to constrain yourself this way in the future.

Comment: So in c++0x can we have allocators with state?? Could you provide a link to the upcoming allocator changes you mention??

Comment: Check out http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#scoped-allocator for a quick survey of the issues involved.

Comment: @TT: Great, that example's exactly my use-case - separate arenas for multi-threading. Do you know what's intended with `list::splice` when the list's have unequal allocators. I guess the elements will actually be "move'd" from one list to another, rather than the current pointer reshuffling??

Comment: @Darren: According to section 23.3.5.5 of N3291 (the most recent working draft of C++0x), the two iterators must compare equal. Otherwise, the result is undefined, but no exception is thrown. I imagine that a good debugging STL implementation will complain, and rightfully so.